# How to get merged array from multiple rows in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables bets and users.

bets columns

1. tickets (json)
2. draw_date
3. user_id

I would like to get all tickets from users of a specific draw_date.

Example result:

```
[
 1 => [283983, 389239, 484843],
 2 => [122343, 332344]
]
```

1, 2 will be the user ids. Tickets array will contain tickets from all bets of a individual user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(ticket) AS tickets
FROM bets
WHERE draw_date = 'specific_draw_date'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Can you please convert it to Laravel Eloquent Builder?

Comment: @NaungYeHtet you had to use [tag:laravel-query-builder], i don't think eloquent support `JSON_ARRAYAGG` directly. also, if it doesn't resolve your problem refrain from marking as answer.

Comment: @NaungYeHtet $result = DB::table('bets')
    ->select('user_id', DB::raw('JSON_ARRAYAGG(ticket) as tickets'))
    ->where('draw_date', '=', $specificDrawDate)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Bet; // Assuming your model for the 'bets' table is Bet

$specificDrawDate = 'your_specific_draw_date'; // Replace with the actual date

$results = Bet::select('user_id', DB::raw('JSON_ARRAYAGG(tickets) as tickets'))->where('draw_date', $specificDrawDate)->groupBy('user_id')->get()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
// Assuming tickets are stored as JSON arrays in the database
   return [$item->user_id => json_decode($item->tickets)];
});
```